# Real Analysis question in Second Fundamental Theory of Calc

Tags: real-analysis

Define

$$F(x)=\int_1^x \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}-1} dt   \quad \text{for all $x\ge 1$}.$$

Prove that if c>0, then there is a unique solution to the equation

$$F(x)=c, \quad x>1.$$

Attempt at a solution: I am not sure how to "prove" this. What I have so far is that $\int_1^x \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}-1} dt= \sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{2} ln(2\sqrt{x}-1)-1$. If F(x)=c, and x>1, then F(x) will always be positive so clearly there will be a unique solution to F(x)=c...there must be a trick I am not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$F'(x) = {1\over 2\sqrt{x}+1}$$
for $x > 1$.
The function $F$ is strictly increasing, and $F(0) = 0$.  Note that as $x\to\infty$, $F(x) \uparrow\infty$.

Therefore, for all $c > 0$, $F(x) = c$ has a unique solution.

Comment: Helped so much thank you! One quick question, how did you get the "+" on the bottom? I keep going through and am getting $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}-1}$

Comment: You have $F'(x)$ behaving like ${1\over 2 \sqrt{x}$ at $\infty$, so $F$ is going to increase at $\infty$ like the square-root function.